# Function for the search of the word in dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

My task is to search the word in the values of dictionary (extra_key) and return a key of dict if it was successful, otherwise return 'no'.
My function is working well for the search of the word:

```
def extra(data):
    for x in data:
        for j in extra_key:
            if x in extra_key[j]:
                print('found:', x, j)
                return j

extra(['Cannabidiol', 'supensoid', 'agent', 'for', 'treatment', 
'of', 'arthritis', 'and', 'preparation', 'method', 'thereof'])
```

Output: `found: agent composition` (here everything is ok)

But when I'm trying to return 'no' if the word was not found then it is ignoring my positive result:

```
def extra(data):
    for x in data:
        for j in extra_key:
            if x.lower() in extra_key[j]:
                print('found:', x, j)
                return j
            else:
                return 'no'

extra(['Cannabidiol', 'supensoid', 'agent', 'for', 'treatment', 
'of', 'arthritis', 'and', 'preparation', 'method', 'thereof'])
```

Output: `'no'`

But it should be like in previous case. Why the output is 'no'? And how to fix it?

Comment: What is `extra_key`?

Comment: @Aplet123, it is a dictionary. And it is written inside my question

Comment: `extra_key` is **not** defined in your question.

Comment: I already have a correct answer, Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **one** match doesn't work, you shouldn't return "no" from the function, because there might be other matches. Only return `"no"` if you can't find any match (at the end of the function):

```py
def extra(data):
    for x in data:
        for j in extra_key:
            if x.lower() in extra_key[j]:
                print('found:', x, j)
                return j
    return 'no'
```

This works because if a match is found, `return j` will be called and exit the function early, so it'll never make it to the `return 'no'`. However, if there is no match, the loop will run all the way through and encounter the `return 'no'`.

Comment: It make sense. Thank you! PS I can accept your answer only in 7 min ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are returning 'no' after only checking the first item in the dictionary.  Try:

```
def extra(data):
    for x in data:
        for j in extra_key:
            if x.lower() in extra_key[j]:
                print('found:', x, j)
                return j
    
    return 'no'

extra(['Cannabidiol', 'supensoid', 'agent', 'for', 'treatment', 
'of', 'arthritis', 'and', 'preparation', 'method', 'thereof'])
```

This will return 'no' only if there were no matches by any of the words you passed in.